# Passing parameters for record udf with ascli - bug?

Tags: aerospike

According to the documentation, ascli should be able to take arguments when applying a record udf against a record ([docs on ascli command 'udf-record-apply'](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/ascli/udf_management.html#udf-record-apply)).

However, I have failed to get this to work. Here is a minimal example:

```
-- Minimal failing example
function testfunc(rec, param1, param2, param3)
  local ret = map()

  -- Just print what was passed into UDF
  ret['debug_param1'] = param1
  ret['debug_param2'] = param2
  ret['debug_param3'] = param3
  return ret
end
```

It was registered with `ascli udf-put minimal-example.lua`. When used with aql, the record udf works fine:

```
aql> execute minimal-example.testfunc(12345) on test.test where PK = '1'
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| testfunc                                                       |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| {"debug_param1":12345, "debug_param2":NIL, "debug_param3":NIL} |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 secs)
```

However, when used from cli with param1 = 12345, it ignores any parameters passed to the udf:

```
$ ascli udf-record-apply test test 1 minimal-example testfunc 12345
{ "debug_param1": null, "debug_param2": null, "debug_param3": null }
```

Are my calls to ascli incorrect or is this a bug?

Comment: I found you can use square brackets to pass integers as a single-item list, e.g. `... testfunc [12345] [23456] [34567]`. But it is not as convenient, and I haven't figured how to pass strings in.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, would you like to post this as answer? Will try soon.

Comment: Sure Manuel. It's not the ideal answer but is helpful in some cases.

Comment: Not ideal, solved my problem though :) Deserves some points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass in integer lists (or empty lists) into UDFs via ascli. For example:

`ascli udf-record-apply test test 1 udfModule funcName [123] [234,235] [1,[2]] []`

A couple of notes:
- Parameter passing appears to work only for integer lists (no strings, maps, etc.)
- There's no white space after the comma in the list

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ascli, it is better to use the aql tool which is more feature rich and well maintained.

Comment: Thanks Sunil. We like aql but ascli still got benefits for certain use cases (like automated/scheduled 'cronjobs'). Therefore, we'd use it in the way Aaron found out, but it looks like syntax for parameters or documentation on that could be enhanced to increase ease of use for developers. Or is ascli deprecated / gonna be discontinued soon anyways?